# perl - grep filename in directory

Tags: perl, grep

I have a directory named as - `"Requests"` inside that I have below files

```
 Transition-Request-201405061735.html
 Requisition-Request-201405061735.html
 Transition-Request-201405061735.txt
 Transition-Request-201405061735.csv
 output.txt
```

I need to filter only Transition-Request-201405061735.txt

the code I came up so far is below

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
 use strict;
 use warnings;

   my $Request = "/tmp/Requests";
   opendir(DIR, $Request) or die $!; 
   my @inputfiles = grep { /ion-Request-/ && \/\.txt$/ && -f "$Request/$_"  } readdir(DIR);
   print "@inputfiles\n";
```

Output is as below

```
Transition-Request-201405061735.html Transition-Request-201405061735.csv Transition-Request-201405061735.txt Requisition-Request-201405061735.html
```

I am seeking experts advise in using a valid `grep` statement to filter only my desired file - `Transition-Request-201405061735.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the escape character:

```
  \/\.txt$/
# ^ here
```

just remove it:

```
.... /ion-Request-/ && /\.txt$/ ...
```

Answer (score 1):

This is much more straightforward using [`glob`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html):

```
my @inputfiles = glob '/tmp/Requests/Transition-Request-*.txt';
```